# C# Directory.GetFiles With Extension AND Size Filter

Tags: c#

I want to count the number of files in a folder with a certain extension and that are above X kb in size. Can anyone help on how to do this, please?

I can do the extension part:

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> count the number of files in a folder with a certain extension and
>   that are above X kb in size

You can use  [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx) and `FileInfo.Length`:

```
double minKbFileSize = 500;  
var tempDir = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp\\"); 
int countLargeFiles = tempDir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
   .Count(file => file.Length / 1024d > minKbFileSize);
```

[`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`, so you don't need to create an instance from it as you have to do if you use `Directo.EnumerateFiles`.

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When
>   you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   `FileInfo` objects before the whole collection is returned. When you
>   use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of `FileInfo`
>   objects to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore,
>   when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles`
>   can be more efficient.

I'm using `EnumerateFiles` always when i'm filtering with LINQ.

Comment: That `file.Length` is going to be the length of the filename, not the length of the file.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: no, it's a `FileInfo` object not a string. That's why i've used `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` instead of `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I see you're using `DirectoryInfo` not `Directory`. This seems the best approach to me, then, since it doesn't need a separate step to create `FileInfo` objects.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by creating a `FileInfo` out of every file in the directory, and then querying it's `FileInfo.Length` property:

```
var count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                        @"c:\temp\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .Count(file => new FileInfo(file).Length / 1024 >= size);
```